# Select rows from ColumnDataSource in Bokeh interactive line plot

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am stuck trying to select rows to plot in a simple Bokeh line plot.
The desired result is a simple line plot with `Date` on the x-axis and `Value` on the y-axis.
Using 2 select widgets I would like to select `Country` and `Type`.

Any suggestions a more than welcome!

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, CDSView, GroupFilter
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_notebook()

# base
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Date': ['01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020'],
                   'Type': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],
                   'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

country_filter = CDSView(source=source, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='Country', group='A')])
type_filter = CDSView(source=source, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='Type', group='X')])

country_select = Select(title="Country:", value="A", options=np.unique(source.data['Country']).tolist())
country_select.js_link('value', country_filter, 'group')

type_select = Select(title="Type:", value="X", options=np.unique(source.data['Type']).tolist())
type_select.js_link('value', type_filter, 'group')

p = figure()
p.line(x='Date', y='Value', source=source, view=view)

layout = row(p, column(country_select, type_select))

show(layout)
```

Comment: Your `CustomJS` callback has null effect. You are creating *new local variables* x and y—and then immediately throwing them away. If you want to update things by changing data you have to actually modify the `source` object. But as mentioned below, a `CDSView` is probably also simpler here. https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated my question and code based on your answer. However, my code does not work yet. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Here's a working version. Two things to note:

1. I had to manually link group filters' changes to the view's `change` signal - right now Bokeh doesn't make that link internally
2. Since you're using lines, this code will produce a warning about using filters with glyphs with connected topology. It can safely be ignored in your case

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, CDSView, GroupFilter, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Date': ['01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020',
                            '01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020'],
                   'Type': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],
                   'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

country_filter = GroupFilter(column_name='Country', group='A')
type_filter = GroupFilter(column_name='Type', group='X')
view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[country_filter, type_filter])

# Alas, we need this manual step to make the view know about the filters' changes.
for f in view.filters:
    f.js_on_change('group', CustomJS(args=dict(view=view),
                                     code="view.properties.filters.change.emit();"))

country_select = Select(title="Country:", value="A", options=np.unique(source.data['Country']).tolist())
country_select.js_link('value', country_filter, 'group')

type_select = Select(title="Type:", value="X", options=np.unique(source.data['Type']).tolist())
type_select.js_link('value', type_filter, 'group')

p = figure()
p.line(x='Date', y='Value', source=source, view=view)

show(row(p, column(country_select, type_select)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated my question and code based on your answer. However, my code does not work yet. What am I missing?

Comment: @Rene The `group` attribute must contain the exact value that you want to filter for, and not a name of an attribute. Like `group='A'` for countries or `group='X'` for types (so, you will end up having two filters). I also don't understand why you need to call `js_link` on `sizing_mode` - that should not work at all. Try `select1.js_link('value', country_filter, 'group')`.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don get it working.  updated my code, but can you maybe be complete it?